# ChartControl In WPF

Tags: wpf, charts, devexpress

How to add Point to `ChartControl` in WPF (by Code)

**XAML code**

```
<Grid> 
    <dxc:ChartControl> 
        <dxc:ChartControl.Legends> 
            <dxc:Legend/> 
        </dxc:ChartControl.Legends> 
        <dxc:XYDiagram2D> 
            <dxc:BarSideBySideSeries2D DisplayName="Series 1"/> 
        </dxc:XYDiagram2D> 
    </dxc:ChartControl> 
</Grid>
```

Comment: You may explore https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Chart-Control-in-WPF-c9727c28. I followed this to implements charts in wpf application.

Comment: Add points to chart.Series

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the `SeriesPoint` to `Points` collection from code behind. Like,

```
barSeries.Points.Add(new DevExpress.Xpf.Charts.SeriesPoint { Argument = "A", Value = 1 });
barSeries.Points.Add(new DevExpress.Xpf.Charts.SeriesPoint { Argument = "B", Value = 2 });
barSeries.Points.Add(new DevExpress.Xpf.Charts.SeriesPoint { Argument = "C", Value = 3 });
```

Where, `barSeries` is your `BarSideBySideSeries2D` series.

Answer (score 0):

You can [add points to a series manually](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/7920/Controls-and-Libraries/Charts-Suite/Chart-Control/Providing-Data/Add-Points-to-a-Series-Manually):

```
...
<dxc:BarSideBySideSeries2D.Points>
    <dxc:SeriesPoint Argument="A" Value="1" />
    <dxc:SeriesPoint Argument="B" Value="2" />
    <dxc:SeriesPoint Argument="C" Value="3" />
    <dxc:SeriesPoint Argument="D" Value="4" />
</dxc:BarSideBySideSeries2D.Points>
...
```

[Here](https://github.com/DevExpress-Examples/how-to-create-a-2d-side-by-side-bar-chart-e1257) is the full-fledged example.

Take a look at the [Providing Data](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/6854/Controls-and-Libraries/Charts-Suite/Chart-Control/Providing-Data) help article for more information.

Comment: No i want to write code be hide (.xaml.cs) not (.xaml)